# how to get eastern standard time using time.nist.gov in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Here is what I have but it does not print the eastern standard time

```
from socket import socket

connection = socket()
connection.connect( ('time.nist.gov', 13) )

dayAndTime = connection.recv(1024)

print (dayAndTime)
```

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: It prints UTC, timezone for England

Comment: All of the NIST.gov services return the time in UTC https://www.nist.gov/time-distribution/internet-time-service-its You have to convert it to your local time.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Search here for 'python timezone conversion' there are lots of resources.

Comment: Just be careful.  Do you want Eastern Standard Time, or Eastern Time.  The former is five hours earlier than UTC.  The latter depends on whether the US is on daylight saving time or not.  (UTC - 5 in winter, UTC - 4 in summer)

Comment: I want Eastern Standard Time

Comment: Also watch this, and get yourself a stiff drink https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY